# Change Button Text in loop using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Is it possible to change button text that is created using array. If it is possible, what should I do with the onClick function in the button. Here is the sample code :

```
function RenderFeeds(props) {
const list = []

props.products.forEach((product) => {
  list.push(
    <>
       <h1>{product.name}</h1>
       <h2>{product.company_name}</h2>
       <h2>{product.description}</h2>
        <button onClick={}>{product.watchlist==false ? 'Add to watchlist':'Remove From watchlist'}</button>
    </>
  )
})

return (
  <>
    {list}
  </>
)}
```

So basically I have an array which contains this value :

```
[{
"name": "lorem ipsum",
"description": "Nam vel nisi rutrum quam ",
"company_name": "PT dapibus ",
"company_slug": "pt-dapibus",
"watchlist": true,
"id": 1
}]
```

I am creating the component using this array. The *watchlist* variable will affect the text in the button. If it is **true** then I want the button to have **Remove From Watchlist** and viceversa.

I am aware that we can use hook in React and apply *useState* for *onClick* button function. But I do not know how do I initialize the state if I use loop to create the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below snippet I've implemented an example, just for keep it simple, I've used static data as list. I hope it could help.

```js
const data = [{ "name": "lorem ipsum", "description": "description1", "company_name": "PT dapibus ", "company_slug": "pt-dapibus", "watchlist": true, "id": 1 },{ "name": "lorem ipsum2", "description": "description2", "company_name": "Google", "company_slug": "company_slug", "watchlist": true, "id": 2 }]

function RenderFeeds({ feeds, onAddToWatch, onRemoveFromWatch }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>{/* or any markup you want */}
      {feeds.map((feed) => (
        <div className="feed" key={feed.id}>
          <h1>{feed.name}</h1>
          <h2>{feed.company_name}</h2>
          <h2>{feed.description}</h2>
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              feed.watchlist
                ? onRemoveFromWatch(feed.id)
                : onAddToWatch(feed.id)
            }
          >
            {feed.watchlist ? 'Remove From watchlist' : 'Add to watchlist'}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Feed() {
  const [feeds, setFeeds] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //receiving data, for example fetching data by ajax or whatever
    setFeeds(data);
  }, []);

  const handleAddToWatch = (id) => {
    // implement updating feeds, for example making an ajax request and getting new data
    setFeeds((feeds) =>
      feeds.map((feed) => ({
        ...feed,
        watchlist: feed.id == id ? true : feed.watchlist,
      }))
    );
  };
  const handleRemoveFromWatch = (id) => {
    // implement updating feeds, for example making an ajax request and getting new data
    setFeeds(feeds =>
      feeds.map((feed) => ({
        ...feed,
        watchlist: feed.id == id ? false : feed.watchlist,
      }))
    );
  };

  return (
      <RenderFeeds
        feeds={feeds}
        onAddToWatch={handleAddToWatch}
        onRemoveFromWatch={handleRemoveFromWatch}
      />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Feed/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.feed{
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.feed h1{ margin: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering stuff based on props, it is not really necessary to use hooks in this case.

Something like this should work:

```js
function RenderFeeds(props) {

return (
  <>
    {props.products.map((product) => {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>{product.name}</h1>
          <h2>{product.company_name}</h2>
          <h2>{product.description}</h2>
          <button onClick={}>{product.watchlist==false ? 'Add to watchlist':'Remove From watchlist'}</button>
        </>
      )
    })}
  </>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create one extra variable `list` and looping over products list which you're getting as props and then pushing it to `list` and then rendering `list` **instead you can directly loop over products list using `map`**. And there is no need to check `product.watchlist==false` when you can use **! [Logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)**

```
function RenderFeeds(props) {

return (
  <>
    {props.products.map((product) => {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>{product.name}</h1>
          <h2>{product.company_name}</h2>
          <h2>{product.description}</h2>
          <button onClick={}>{!product.watchlist ? 'Add to watchlist':'Remove From watchlist'}</button>
        </>
      )
    })}
  </>
)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. But how do I update the product.watchlist value ? Because I want the button to trigger the product.watchlist value so that the button text can alter between 'Add To Watchlist' and 'Remove From Watchlist'

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would highly recommend you to use Array.map() method instead of using Array.forEach() to create an array of List components because Array.map() itself return an array with new mappings.

And the thing or concept you are looking for in solving this problem is called `conditional rendering`.

You can use the `ternary operator` or also known as `conditional operators` for the purpose of doing `conditional rendering` because `JSX expects an expression` that can be evaluated to something.

> <button onClick={()=>alert('Watchlist changed')}>{product.watchlist==true? 'Add to watchlist':'Remove From watchlist'}